# Connect a WiFi Repeater with a Tomato Router

Tags: router, wireless-router, tomato, fritzbox

I recently bought a repeater (http://en.avm.de/products/fritzwlan/fritzwlan-repeater-1750e/) to extend the range of my wifi, but I'm not able to make it work with my router (ASUS RT-68AC) which runs Advanced Tomato (Tomato Firmware 1.28.0000 MIPSR2-3.0-132 K26AC USB AIO-64K).

I'm able to access the control interface of the repeater from both sides (when connected to the router and when connected to the repeater) but when I'm connected with the repeater I cannot access the internet or any other network resource.

Is there anything I have to activate or something like this within the Tomate interface to make this work? I know the repeater basically works because it is already my second device with the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just joined just to answer this question :) I hope you see this answer or this help anyone else.

You need to add a static IP bound to a mac address that is one bit lower to your repeaters MAC address. ex an example;

My repeater's mac address is; xx:xx:xx:E6:5B:CF and I've added a new IP-MAC bound as xx:xx:xx:E6:5B:CE to an IP address and it worked.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  I'm a little confused by your answer.  Doesn't that just specify a different MAC address?  Is there something special about being 1 lower?  Anything you can add to explain how or why this works?  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Creating the static IP works.  Not sure why, but it does.  You only need to create one - doesn't matter how many devices connect to the extender.  Just found this answer and tested it after a very frustrating call with Netgear support.